# Error with jquery-autocomplete in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, autocomplete

I've been trying to get autocomplete to work, however, I am getting a weird javascript error in the firebug console...

I used the *https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete* gem.

The error I am getting reads: `$(e).autocomplete is not a function`

Here are the scripts i am including in my html:

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/autocomplete-rails.js?1294035084" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you change the default javascript library using
[this gem](http://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs)?

It's one of the prerequisite of your gem

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact problem today and fixed it by installing jQuery UI. Apparently rails3-jquery-autocomplete uses the autocomplete functionality that is included in jQuery UI. It will be broken until you install **[jquery-rails](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs)** and include both the jquery UI js and CSS files in your layout.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults, "jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min", "autocomplete-rails" %>
```

Quoting the Github site:

> **Before you start**
>
> Make sure your project is using
> jQuery-ui with the autocomplete widget
> before you continue.
>
> You can find more info about that
> here:
>
> http://jquery.com/
>
> http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/
>
> http://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs
>
> I'd encourage you to understand how to use
> those 3 amazing tools before
> attempting to use this gem.